# Trigonometric integral with different angles and different powers

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'm in Calc II and we've just gotten through trigonometric integrals. My teacher assigned this problem on a quiz:

$\int \cos^3(x) \sin^4(3x) \, dx$

I can't find any tricks in the book and wolfram alpha gave this:

$\int \cos^3(x) \sin^4(3x) dx = $

$\dfrac{sin^5(x)}{30030}
  (202005 \cos(2x) + 102480 \cos(4x) + 36435 \cos(6x) + 
  8470 \cos(8 x) + 1001 \cos(10x) + 136095)
 + C$

And that doesn't seem right. Does anyone know of a trick to make these angles equivalent, or make a "prettier" looking solution?

[My Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUAZV.jpg)

As you can see I stopped when I realized how many integrations by parts I was about to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know that $$\cos 3x=4\cos^3 x-3\cos x$$
$$\implies \cos^3 x=\frac{\cos 3x +3\cos x}{4}$$
Putting this in the integral, and breaking it into two parts yields,
$$\frac{1}{4}\int \cos {3x} \sin^4{3x} dx+ \frac{3}{4} \int \cos x \sin^4{3x}dx$$
The first one is trivial, just substitute $\sin 3x=t$ to get $\frac{sin^5 3x}{60}$
For the next one, notice that
$$\sin 3x = 3\sin x -4\sin^3 x$$
Putting it into the integral gives
$$ \int \cos x(3\sin x-4 \sin^3 x)^4 dx$$
You may put $\sin x =t$ to get,
$$\int (3t-4t^3)^4dt$$
Which you may open via the binomial theorem and integrate (will be messy), so W|A is probably right.